# Using separate library within play framework

Tags: xml, json, scala, playframework

I tried using the lift-json library to convert XML to JSON in the following way:
http://mkaz.com/solog/scala/how-to-convert-xml-to-json.html

in my controller.scala file. I then get the error:

The file /app/controllers.scala could not be compiled. Error raised is : missing arguments for method Xml in class ScalaController; follow this method with '_' if you want to treat it as a partially applied function

The error was highlighting:

```
val str = Printer.pretty(render(↓Xml.toJson(data)))
```

I tried running my same code in another file and it worked, but it still does not work in the play framework.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're not getting compiler warnings on symbols hiding other symbols - I'm not clear on where the error is exactly, but it's possible one of the symbols you import has overridden *render*. If that's the case you can rename on import like so:

```
import net.liftweb.json.{render => renderJson}
// ...
val str = Printer.pretty(renderJson(Xml.toJson(data)))
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a typo in the line. See the down arrow just before `Xml`? It shouldn't be there, but, since it is, it interprets `Xml` as a method.